# List columns with sqoop

Tags: sqoop

I have found the following commands very usefull to see what my source database looks like:

```
sqoop-list-databases
sqoop-list-tables
```

However, there does not appear to be a command to list the columns in a table, which would be a logical step.

My question is now:

## How can I get the list of columns from a table via Sqoop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no command like `sqoop-list-columns`, however with some creativity there is a workaround:

### Run an import, and import the fieldnames.

Here is an example, for how this can be done when connecting to a SQL Server database:

```
sqoop import --m 1 --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://nameofmyserver; database=nameofmydatabase; username=dennisjaheruddin; password=mypassword' --query "SELECT column_name, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns WHERE table_name='mytableofinterest' AND \$CONDITIONS" --target-dir 'mytableofinterest_column_name'
```

This will retreive the column names and write them to a file, which you can then inspect manually.

Of course this can be expanded to get other metadata (e.g. field types).
Note that you will need a slightly different SELECT statement if you are connecting to a different database type, but that should be easy to find.

Comment: If you are connecting to a different kind of database, you need a different query of course. For instance a describe for MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Use "Describe DB_name.table_name" in sqoop eval.

sqoop eval --connect Connection_string --username username --password password --query "describe DB_Name.Table_Name"

Comment: This is a nice example of the query you would use when connecting to a MySQL database.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know the column names for some source table, Below is the easiest way to deal
**SQOOP EVAL**
Below is the example for pulling the column names from oracle database, its the same for all the RDBMS

**sqoop eval** **-libjars** /var/lib/sqoop/ojdbc6.jar **--connect** jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:portnumber/servicename **--username** user **-password** password **--query** "select *  from schemaname.tablename where rownum=10"

This will print the schema on the terminal. in the query section you can run any query that you want to run on the rdbms.

Lets say you want to store the output, just append it to a file as below.
**sqoop eval -libjars** /var/lib/sqoop/ojdbc6.jar **--connect** jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:portnumber/servicename **--username** user **-password** password **--query** "select *  from schemaname.tablename where rownum=10" >> sqoop_results.txt

Answer (score 0):

use the below command in sqoop eval query:
"describe database_name.table_name"

This command worked for me :

sqoop eval --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/database_name --username root -P --query "describe database_name.table_name"

The command output will be as below :

[cloudera@localhost ~]$ sqoop eval --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/mytestdb --username root -P --query "describe mytestdb.CustomersNew3"

17/01/26 22:13:08 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.3-cdh4.7.0
Enter password:

### 17/01/26 22:13:12 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.

### | COLUMN_NAME          | COLUMN_TYPE          | IS_NULLABLE | COLUMN_KEY | COLUMN_DEFAULT       | EXTRA                |

| ID                   | int(11)              | NO  |     | (null)               |                      | 
| NAME                 | varchar(20)          | NO  |     | (null)               |                      | 
| AGE                  | int(11)              | NO  |     | (null)               |                      | 
| ADDRESS              | char(25)             | YES |     | (null)               |                      |

### | SALARY               | decimal(18,2)        | YES |     | (null)               |                      |

Comment: This is a nice example of the query you would use when connecting to a MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage `sqoop eval` command for this purposes.

Example in Netezza:

```
sqoop eval --connect 'jdbc:netezza://host:port/db' --username 'your_user' --password 'your_pass' --query "SELECT column_name, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns WHERE table_name='your_table'"
```

This will output result to console:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| column_name          | data_type            | 
-----------------------------------------------
| col1                 | bigint               | 
| col2                 | bigint               | 
| col3                 | bigint               | 
| col4                 | integer              |
```